# Fetching the Image from Amazon to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I used this script to fetch the image of an ASIN from Amazon.

After saving the Script, I already used the fetchAndResizeImage custom function assuming that the asin is in cell A1. =fetchAndResizeImage(A1). But the result is not image not found. I also tried adjusting the image size, still image not found.

```
function fetchAndResizeImage(asin) {
  var url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/" + asin;
  var imageUrl = fetchImageUrl(url);

  if (imageUrl) {
    var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
    var resizedImageBlob = resizeImage(imageBlob, 10, 10); // Adjust the size as needed
    return resizedImageBlob;
   } else {
     return "Image not found";
   }
 }

 function fetchImageUrl(url) {
   try {
     var htmlContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
     var imageUrl = /"large":"(https:[^"]+)"/.exec(htmlContent)[1];
     return imageUrl;
   } catch (error) {
     return null;
    }
 }

function resizeImage(imageBlob, width, height) {
  var image = ImagesApp.open(imageBlob);
  var resizedImage = image.getResizedImage(width, height);
   return resizedImage.getBlob();
 }
```

Comment: FWIW, for the clueless among us (that's me folks): Amazon Standard Identification Number (ASIN) is a ten-digit alphanumeric code that identifies products on Amazon. It’s unique for each product and is assigned when you create a new product in Amazon’s catalog.

Comment: May I ask where you got this script? And what is your reason for believing that this script will fetch an amazon image?

Comment: Related question: [Fetching Amazon Product Image by ASIN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58142293/1330560)

Comment: Is this not possible?